# CloudFormation removing AWS Cognito Lambda Triggers on update stack operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I️ have noticed whenever a new CloudFormation stack change is deployed, my User Pool triggers are removed and have to be manually re-added within the AWS dashboard or programmatically. This is a bit of a concern as these triggers conduct some crucial operations with communication between Cognito and the backend system.

At first I️ thought it was the deployment framework we are using, but here is a barebones example of a CF template I️ was able to replicate it with:

Updated to reflect Lambda attachment to User Pool

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "UserPool": {
      "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
      "Properties": {
        "UserPoolName": "test",
        "UsernameAttributes": [
          "email"
        ],
        "EmailVerificationMessage": "Your verification code is {####}.",
        "EmailVerificationSubject": "Your verification code",
        "Policies": {
          "PasswordPolicy": {
            "MinimumLength": 8,
            "RequireLowercase": true,
            "RequireNumbers": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "UserPoolClient": {
      "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient",
      "Properties": {
        "ClientName": "Test Client",
        "UserPoolId": {
          "Ref": "UserPool"
        },
        "ExplicitAuthFlows": [
          "ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
          "ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
          "ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH"
        ],
        "GenerateSecret": false
      }
    },
    "PreSignUpHandlerLambdaFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::...",
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": "code-bucket",
          "S3Key": "code-bucket/functions.zip"
        },
        "Handler": "handlers/pre-sign-up.default",
        "Runtime": "nodejs12.x",
        "FunctionName": "test-preSignUpHandler",
        "MemorySize": 1024,
        "Timeout": 6
      }
    },
    "PreSignUpHandlerCustomCognitoUserPool1": {
      "Type": "Custom::CognitoUserPool",
      "Version": 1,
      "DependsOn": [
        "PreSignUpHandlerLambdaFunction"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:...",
        "FunctionName": "test-preSignUpHandler",
        "UserPoolName": "test",
        "UserPoolConfigs": [
          {
            "Trigger": "PreSignUp"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I️ have dug into CloudWatch logs generated by the update, but nothing is transparent regarding the User Pool update and the removal of the triggers.
Has anyone else experienced this and are there any work-arounds?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior of CloudFormation. When config drift is detected on stack update it will bring it back in line with your stack template. If you want to retain the changes you should specify the triggers in your CFN template. Be sure to grant cognito access in the resource policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "default",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "lambda-allow-cognito-my-function",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource":  "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:my-function",
            "Condition": {
              "StringEquals": {
                "AWS:SourceAccount": "123456789012"
              },
              "ArnLike": {
                "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:123456789012:userpool/us-east-1_myUserPoolId"
              }
            }
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Specifying triggers in the CF template also detaches them, that is how the problem originated.

Comment: You’ve assigned the correct lambda permission to allow cognito execution access?

Comment: Hey Andrew, I️ appreciate your attention on this. Yes, all of the triggers have invocation access and this behavior is still persisted even when specified as a trigger in the CF template. I've updated my post to reflect a more accurate version of what is being deployed.

Comment: I️ have noticed our deployment framework does attach the Lambda's in a non-conventional way (it generates CF templates from YML). I️ am referring to the "Custom::CognitoUserPool" resource I've included in the updated example.

Comment: Serverless. https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/

Comment: So just so I'm getting this right... you are deploying the userpool in a separate CFN stack and then attaching the trigger handlers using serverless framework (in its own stack)?

Comment: If so this behavior isn't avoidable as lambda triggers are configuration values of the userpool and serverless framework's magic custom resources are modifying it outside cloudformation. Either define them in the same stack or don't use the serverless event helper and manually pass the arns in your userpool stack

Comment: No, user pool and its triggers are being deployed in one CF stack. I️ have noticed the detachment happens whenever the User Pool Config is modified (i.e. adding an EmailConfiguration), so perhaps this is expected behavior based on your previous comments. It is puzzling though, considering that in that stack update there are still custom resources attaching said triggers to the UP.

Comment: You're overriding the userpool config [as specified here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cognito-user-pool#overriding-a-generated-user-pool)?

Comment: Andrew - sorry for the delay. Yes, that is exactly how I️ am deploying.

Comment: Any chance you set `existing` to `true` in your event mapping?

Comment: I️ indeed am, but if I️ recall, this is necessary as it marks that that user pool already exists. Otherwise, Serverless tries to create a new one (which would fail due to name conflicts)

Comment: … well that’s the problem. You need to follow their logical ID convention and remove that`existing` flag. That is meant for resource created external to the stack.